# Determine if the gpg-agent cached credentials are still valid

Tags: gpg

In a shell script I would like to check if the `gpg-agent` has valid cached credentials or not. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Until something better comes along I have settled on this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if gpg --batch --output=/dev/null --clearsign /etc/services 2> /dev/null; then
    echo "Congratulations! Your GPG credentials are ready."
    exit 0
else
    echo "gpg-agent does not have valid cached credentials"
    exit 2
fi
```